# How to traverse between elements in jsoup to extract table names for the corresponding tables

Tags: jsoup, dom-traversal

I have a html file, where I need to extract the table headings for the respective tables, however the headings and tables are in different div sections . My current idea is that since we can directly access all tables in a html file and given the font size of table content is less than the font size of table name most of the times, I want to use the each of the list of table elements as a pivot to traverse back to identify elements that are of bigger font size, however I am not sure how can acheive this.

I am a beginner to jsoup , so I thought I could get some advice on node traversal. Appreciate any other alternative approaches as well.

For example in the below link https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/713676/000119312515070443/d836469d10k.htm 
I need to extract the table in page 26 table and tag a name to the table that is "EXECUTIVE OFFICERS OF THE REGISTRANT" . 
While extracting tables is easy part, I am not sure how I can extract the "name of the table" . 
One option I thought is by using traversing between sibling nodes via previousElementSibling method to verify the font size in the attributes and comparing with the captured table font size, if none of the siblings give a font size bigger, I traverse to parent level and surveillance into their children. However the bigger challenge is does this method generalizes well to other documents or not.

Comment: Could you give us an example of the HTML? I fear that using the font size may not work, because this might be set via css and is therefore not directly part of the HTML that you want to parse. Also, please give a a little source code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/713676/000119312515070443/d836469d10k.htm

Comment: Unfortunately I am still unable to write any code that answers this yet, but all I am just trying to do is traversing between sibling nodes via previousElementSibling method to verify the font size in the attributes and comparing with the captured table font size, if none of the siblings give a font size bigger, i traverse to parent level and surveillance into their children .

Comment: This is a truly horrible HTML document. I feel honestly sorry for you that you need to parse this. I am still not sure what table headings you mean. Please edit your question (not more comments) to add infos. Make an example of what you expect to get and extract the relevant part of the HTML. A link may go stale and then the question is useless for others to seek for help here

Comment: The parent of your table is a DIV. The title is also inside this parent DIV. A simple thing you can do is parsing all tables, getting its parent, then check if its text() contains the title (case sensitive) "EXECUTIVE OFFICERS OF THE REGISTRANT". The first table matching this is your table.